# apache2 and ssl module

Tags: apache, ssl

I am trying to enable `ssl` for a `django` webapp in apache webserver in ubuntu lucid.I followed [this article](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/) on configuring apache for ssl
I have unpacked the `apache2 tar.gz` file from `apache website`. When I checked the folders ,I found that it does not contain any `sites-available` directory or `sites-enabled` directory.

How do I proceed? should I delete the entire apache folder and build using source code?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would install webmin.. in [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) you just go to servers->apache->modules and activate the checkbox "ssl" after apache reboot ssl is activated. You can also edit your ssl options in the webmin configuration. I am a software developer and not an administrator so webmin saved me a lot of problems and time, maybe it will help you too.